# i and a tag in same line

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

this is my html

```
<td style="">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <a href="...">Modifica</a>
    <i class="fa fa-th-list"></i> <a href="...">Dettaglio</a>
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <a href="...">Elimina</a>
</td>
```

the result is the following:

[image]

I would like the links to be "attached" to the icon, without breaking the line. How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Impossible to tell without seeing the CSS. Both `<i>` and `<a>` elements are flow content, so the styling must be specifying block display on one of the elements or the `<td>` must have a width that is causing them to wrap.

Comment: Is the table wide enough to fit both the icon and the text in one line? It seems quite narrow. If yes, then make sure the `display` properties of both to be `inline` or `inline-block`

Comment: post css for width of contain div and how much width you give that content?

Comment: Your code is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1049/ check your <a> and <i> tags were having display:block/ clear

Answer (score 4):

May be you don't have enough space for it,you can try

```
<td style="">
    <p style="white-space:nowrap">
        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <a href="...">Modifica</a>
    </p>
    <p style="white-space:nowrap">
        <i class="fa fa-th-list"></i> <a href="...">Dettaglio</a>
    </p>
    <p style="white-space:nowrap">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <a href="...">Elimina</a>
    </p>
</td>
```

Comment: Suggest to put styles in external CSS than inline.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your screenshot, your table seems quite narrow. If the icon and text cannot fit in one line, they will break into 2 separate lines.

So if you want them to be in one line, make sure the `td` has enough width to contain them both.

If they do have space, double-check that your `a` and `i` elements have either `inline` or `inline-block` as `display` property (though this should be default).

Again, it seems your table just isn't wide enough. Try increasing its' width a bit.